# How to cache images and text from data pulled from an API

Tags: java, android, json, picasso

I need some help with my first app. I made a travel guide app that pulls information and image links from a JSON using a retrofit API.

My app works great online, pulling all the data, but now I want the user to be able to view all the information offline once they have cached it.

Client API

```
public static final String BASE_URL = "https://quarkbackend.com";
public static Retrofit retrofit = null;

public static Retrofit getClient(){
    if (retrofit==null){
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
```

Service API

```
public interface Service {
    @GET("/getfile/beyond-infinity-gd/homepage")
    Call<AlbumsResponse> getHomepage();

    @GET("/getfile/beyond-infinity-gd/tours")
    Call<AlbumsResponse> getTours();

    ...
```

Adapter

```
public class AlbumsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AlbumsAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private Context mContext;
private List<Album> albumList;

public AlbumsAdapter(Context mContext, List<Album> albumList) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.albumList = albumList;
}

@Override
public AlbumsAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.album_card, viewGroup, false);

    return new MyViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final AlbumsAdapter.MyViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    viewHolder.title.setText(albumList.get(i).getTitle());
    viewHolder.count.setText(albumList.get(i).getSubtitle());

    //load album cover using picasso
    Picasso.with(mContext)
            .load(albumList.get(i).getThumbnail())
            .placeholder(R.drawable.load)
            .into(viewHolder.thumbnail);


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return albumList.size();
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView title, count;
    public ImageView thumbnail;

    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        count = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.count);
        thumbnail = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);

        //on item click
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                int pos = getAdapterPosition();
                if (pos != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                    Album clickedDataItem = albumList.get(pos);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, DetailActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("title", albumList.get(pos).getTitle());
                    intent.putExtra("subtitle", albumList.get(pos).getSubtitle());
                    intent.putExtra("body", albumList.get(pos).getBody());
                    intent.putExtra("thumbnail", albumList.get(pos).getThumbnail());
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: i think you can storage the information inside SQLite

Answer (score 0):

To cache text data you can use SQLite. Check [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm) tutorial and to cache images you should take a look at Glide/Picasso libraries. They can store images in memory/disk.

Comment: I've been trying to use the NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE but it doesn't work with .load(albumList.get(i).getThumbnail())

It works with simple .load(url) but not with my method.

Answer (score 0):

For caching images I strongly recommend you using [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) or [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) or you can try doing it manually following this official android [guide](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/cache-bitmap.html).

As for storing text data in case of primitive data types the fastest way is to store your data in [Shared Preferences](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref). For more complex business logic and more capabilities, you should use [SQLite](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html).